# How many products have multiple prices? Do not count the same product twice

Tags: mysql, count

How many products have multiple prices?
Do not count the same product twice.
This question i am struggling with because it almost contradicts itself. If someone could point me in the right direction. I have tried everything.
i have attached an image because i was not sure how to copy and paste my code from mysql
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By not counting the same product twice, I think that means only report each product once regardless of whether it has 2, 3, 5 or a million different prices, so don't report every difference, just a summary of which products have multiples. That's just a guess.

Anyway, something like this will list every product that has more than one price:

```
SELECT productid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY productid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) > 1;
```

This will filter out all products with just a single price, leaving only those with more than one.

And if you want to count them, just jam the query above into a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT productid
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY productid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) > 1
) multprod;
```

`multprod` above is just an alias for the subquery. I added it because I can't remember if MySQL requires one.